# Model doesn't learn from data

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network

We have a dataset with ~40000 data points each having 160 features. We know nothing about what each feature represents, but they are 0-5 integers, most probably some rankings. Our task is to take a subset of those features, lets say (40000,30) and predict the initial (40000,160) data. In other words, we need to create a model, that takes 30 features as input and outputs the full 160 set of features.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko6nR.png

the example of the dataset.

What we have done so far, we trained a ANN with the following architecture:
30->200->150->163

We are calculating an accuracy score by rounding the prediction(lets say I predicted 3.6 for 4, 3.6~4, 4==4, so True)

We got ~52% accuracy and nothing makes it go higher.
So, the problem is a multi-output regression problem. The prediction is done using 30 discrete numeric features. The normalization was done both by using Min-Max Scaling and Standardization(The target is also normalized). In the model, we tried different number of layers with different capacity, tried to use batch-norm, different activations (relu is used now, for the output layer no activation is used), different losses (mse is the current one), different optimizers (adam is the current one). Both Keras and PyTorch is used in the case something is wrong with the PyTorch implementation.

So, the accuracy still remains 50-52%. There is one straightforward thing - when we increase the model capacity (the number of parameters) the model is more prone to overfitting. Even after increasing the model capacity very very much, we couldn't make the model overfit the data. We tried to use the features separately (For example, predict one feature from another) - nothing useful. Tried to predict 1 feature using 159 features, but again ~52% and even less.

What I understand and can conclude from these - there is no relationship between those ratings and most of them can't predict others. What do you think about this case?

Comment: Why do you think 52% is a bad accuracy?! What's the accuracy using naïve Bayes?

Comment: Assuming ratings are distributed homogeneously (don't use this assumption for NB, but it's the only I can do): guessing a single feature, you'll expect an accuracy of 20%. Getting a whole row correctly would have a chance of 1e-91, and half of a row 1e-46. 52% looks impressive to me.

Comment: Why do you round the predictions to calculate accuracy? If the right answer is 4, you shouldn't consider equally good a model that predicts 3.6 than one that predicts 3.9.

Comment: **"most probably some rankings"**: This is a critical statement. Because if they're rankings indeed, it means your data is ordered. If they're not, maybe they should be treated as unordered categories(e.g. answers in a multiple choice). So, calculations of any score including a baseline would be different. E.g. in my previous _naïve_ reasoning, I calculated the baseline as if they were unordered.